# why is ?Length=4 being appended to my URL's

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2012, web

I'm learning how to use Visual Studio Express 2012. To do so I am converting a regular website (personal) into an ASP.NET C# website. However, I am encountering a problem I can't resolve. `?Length=4` is being appended to my URL's automatically, but I can't find the source.

My `Html.ActionLink` code is as follows:

```
<div class="navpane">@Html.ActionLink(" ", "About", "Home", new {style="background: url('../images/sticky-who.png') no-repeat; display:block; height:150px; width:150px;"})</div>

<div class="navpane">@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Resume", "Home", new {style="background: url('../images/sticky-resume.png') no-repeat; display:block; height:150px; width:150px;"})</div>
```

I'm stumped. Anyone got a clue?

Comment: By the way, I got the code for adding images here: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers

Answer (score 2):

You are using the incorrect overload. What you have is:

```
Html.ActionLink(string, string, string, object)
```

..which resolves to:

```
Html.ActionLink(string, string, object, object)
```

Which is:

```
Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, Object routeValues, Object htmlAttributes)
```

You need to use this overload:

```
Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, Object routeValues, Object htmlAttributes)
```

`htmlAttributes` goes at the end. You're currently passing `routeValues` as `"Home"`.. hence `Length=4`.

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "About", "Home", null, new {style="background: url('../images/sticky-who.png') no-repeat; display:block; height:150px; width:150px;"})
//                                     ^^^^ The important part
```